# Connect bot with facebook

Tags: facebook, botframework

I built a bot using Microsoft bot composer
then I followed this documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-facebook?view=azure-bot-service-4.0
to connect it with facebook messenger and I get this error, even that the bot work probably in the emulator/ teams/ web chat and I have luis and adaptive card in my bot.

[image]

any ideas?

Comment: Facebook Messenger doesn't support Adaptive Cards, and I suspect the problem you're encountering has to do with [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/1806) because activities from Messenger don't populate their `locale` properties. Are you using choice inputs and confirm inputs? Can you provide some repro steps, or reproduce this with an out-of-the-box Composer sample?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the problem is the bot received the locale as null, and that makes a problem with luis recognizer :)